# UIImageViewController...how to add subview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UIImageViewController Object that implements the delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Within that delegate method I am trying to present a UIActivityIndicatorView to alert the user that the image is writing to a directory. I have tried multiple ways to access the view and add the UIActivityIndicator object to no avail.

```
    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    CGPoint ctr = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    activity.center = ctr;

    [picker.navigationController.visibleViewController.view addSubview:activity]; 
    [activity startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't `[picker.view addSubview:activity];` work? What happens if you try this, because you said that you have already tried. (whatever multiple ways means)

Comment: I was calling [self.imageController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] after the image wrote to the directory. Using [picker.view addSubview:activiy] it appears only after the image writes to the directory. How can I have it appear before it writes the image?